# What's the valid term for a “base” for plants?

Tags: terminology

In case of some plants you can take their cuttings to multiply them. The cuttings are put in the ground directly, so you can have multiple seedlings based on one plant. You can have dozens of plants which are used for this process.

Boxwood or jasmine can both be a good example of such plant.

The term which describes such a group of plants in my language is "matecznik", which is a variation of the word mother.

What's the correct term for such a group of plants? I'm looking for the name of the group of the plants that other plants were grown from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are generally known as ***'stock'*** plants.

> ### Definition of stock plant
>
> **Definition as written by talinum:**
>
> A plant used to obtain propagating material, whether seed or vegetative material.

*source of definition:* http://davesgarden.com/guides/terms/go/1219/#b

as well as others.

Comment: Thank you, it almost answers my question - is there any term that explicitly describes a group of stock plants?

Comment: "**Clones**", perhaps.

Comment: @Ecnerwal "Clones" would be the term for the plants resulting from propagating the stock plants (if by cutting or similar)

Comment: @emilos Why not use 'stock plants' (as opposed to 'stock plant') to describe a group, since it's plural? A group of stock plants is just more than one stock plant. 'Stock plants' is also just more than one stock plant. To refer to a specific group, you might just say 'my stock plants', or 'Sally's tomato stock plants', or 'those stock plants' or what-have-you. We perhaps need to know more about the kind of group you're looking for, and the context in which the terminology is used, to give a more precise answer.

Comment: @Shule the reason why I'm asking is that I didn't find any similar term to the one used in my language and I was curious. "Stock plants" is of course valid and it explaines what the plants are for, but it's not a single word term that would  match the one described in the question.